# Insert using a raw SQL query to avoid SQL injection?

Tags: laravel

I have personalized tables and a bunch of composite keys in my database so I am using raw SQL queries to perform the CRUD operations needed. I found a way to make an insert following the documentation and it worked, but I am wondering, isn't this method vulnerable to SQL injection? I am using the user's input to insert this data and I don't see where's the sanitization of it, maybe I am just wrong though. Can you guide me? Here's my code:

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
    /*No composite keys here so I am using Eloquent*/
        $song = new Song();
        $song->code = $request->code;
        $song->title = $request->title;
        $song->artist = $request->artist;
        $song->length = $request->length;
        $song->album = $request->album;
        $song->save();

        $genre = new Genre();
        $genre->id_gen = $request->genre;
        $genre->id_song = $request->code;
        DB::insert('INSERT INTO genres (id_gen, id_song) values (?, ?)', [$genre->id_gen, $genre->id_song]);
        return $song;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an insert in this fashion does not mean a SQL injection risk as this is what is known as a *parameterized query*. You are generating a query as a string, and then the database system performs its own properly managed replacements to construct the query. I can't recall if this is done at the database or driver level.

What you have done is exactly what Laravel does internally anyway (construct parameterized queries).

In terms of your actual code, you're doing something a little odd. By creating the `Genre` object, applying your request to it and saving, you're doing an insert anyway. There is no real need for the raw insert;

Be sure to validate your request object!

Comment: To sum up, insert statement is safe, but remove that entire line because it's not necessary. Replace it with `$genre->save()` =)

Answer (score 0):

The query uses placeholders (in other words the query-string can be stored as a template or as a constant).

This gives the sql-engine a chance to convert the query to a prepared-statement.

I do not have any knowledge of laravel but this looks like a legitimate use of prepared statements (and consequently immune to sql injection).

In other words the approach looks safe (atleast w.r.t sql-injection).